# How to reuse subfields in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have interfaces defined below:

```
interface One {
  one: {
    oneone: string;
    fieldA: string;
    fieldB: string;
    fieldC: string;
  }
}
```

```
interface Two {
  two: {
    twotwo: string;
    fieldA: string;
    fieldB: string;
    fieldC: string;
  }
}
```

As you can see, `fieldA`, `fieldB`, and `fieldC` are sharable. Is there anyway we can share them? Something like

```
interface SharedFields {
    fieldA: string;
    fieldB: string;
    fieldC: string;
}

interface One {
  one: (extends SharedFields) {
    oneone: string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) for this:

```js
interface SharedFields {
    fieldA: string;
    fieldB: string;
    fieldC: string;
}

interface One {
  one: SharedFields & {
    oneone: string;
  }
}
```